# Underbrace under square root sign plain TeX

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex, underbrace, sqrt

[image]

```
$$
\rlap{$\sqrt{\phantom{\displaystyle\pmatrix{A^{-1} b(x)\cr -1}^T 
        \pmatrix{A & b(x) \cr b(x)^T & \Phi(x,x)}
        \pmatrix{A^{-1} b(x) \cr -1}}}$}
        \mskip14mu
        \displaystyle\pmatrix{A^{-1} b(x)\cr -1}^T 
        \underbrace{\displaystyle
        \pmatrix{A & b(x) \cr b(x)^T & \Phi(x,x)}}%
             _{\displaystyle A_{\Phi, X\cup\{x\}}}
        \pmatrix{A^{-1} b(x) \cr -1}
$$

\bye
```

Is there a better way to obtain the same effect, without having to repeat the formula and manually adding a space (`\mskip14mu`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could (a) apply a `\smash` instruction to the `\underbrace{...}_{...}` part and (b) insert a `\vphantom` directive *after* the `\sqrt{...}` part.

[image]

```
$$
      \sqrt{
         \pmatrix{A^{-1} \cr -1}^{\!T} 
         \smash{\underbrace{\pmatrix{A & b(x) \cr b(x)^T & \Phi(x,x)}}%
                _{\textstyle A_{\Phi, X\cup\{x\}}}}
         \pmatrix{A^{-1} b(x) \cr -1}
      }
      \vphantom{\underbrace{\pmatrix{.\cr .}}_{\textstyle A_{\Phi}}}
$$
\bye
```

Observe that I've also dropped some `\displaystyle` directives and have converted others to `\textstyle`.

Answer (score 6):

TeX can measure the object:

```
$$
\def\contentsA{\pmatrix{A^{-1} b(x) \cr -1}}
\def\contentsB{\pmatrix{A & b(x) \cr b(x)^T & \Phi(x,x)}}
\setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle
  \contentsA^{\!T}
  {\underbrace{\!\contentsB\!}_{\displaystyle A_{\Phi, X\cup\{x\}}}}
  \contentsA
$}
\sqrt{\vphantom{\contentsA^T}\hphantom{\copy0}}
\kern-\wd0
\box0
$$

\bye
```

[image]

I made a couple of changes: braces like `{\underbrace{...}_{...}}` in order to avoid it being considered a math operator with an excess of spacing; for the same reason I introduced a couple of `\!` tokens. And also one for the exponent in order to place it nearer the top of the parenthesis.